# How to map translations to a database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I want in the moment that an user register in my system, he chooses the language (tbParam[language]) and based on the language that he choose the Countries available to him are already translated

When the user register in my system he's able to choose a language, that gets stored into **tbParam[language]**, and with that choosen language the rest of the website would get translated accordingly.

First I thought about doing it via resources on my C#, with a Key and Value, as so:
[Resources screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQTV7.png) on the left it's the name in the default language (portuguese) and the value is the key translated to English, it works just fine for one language but I pretend on doing it for Spanish, German, and English. Then I thought about all the work on doing it and I thought of the second way.

Second way: Using a database

I was thinking about creating some tables that contains the languages, the countries and the translations. Which all of them are linked to each other, by the time that you choose the language, the database for the translations by the language key and handle the result of the query in my c# code.

I would like to know which way is the best, if it's the Database one then what would be the best approach regarding the table relantionships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a resource file for each language. All you need is to include several resources files to your project:

e.g. add resource file names YourResourceFileName.resx.
them to add a resource file for a specific language add the resource file named YourResourceFileName.[CULTURECODE].resx 
For spanish add YourResourceFileName.es.resx 
For German add YourResourceFileName.de.resx 
(You can even use a resource file por a specific culture like en-US or en-GB)

Then consider edit the .csproj file directly and include the new files as dependencies of the previous one(you can right click the project, select "Unload Project" then right click again and select "Edit .csproj" - when done, reload the project via the right click.

You will need to change:

```
<Compile Include="YourResourceFileName.es.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>YourResourceFileName.es.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="YourResourceFileName.es.resx">
```

to:

```
<Compile Include="YourResourceFileName.es.resx">
  <DependentUpon>YourResourceFileName.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

This will put both YourResourceFileName.es.resx and YourResourceFileName.es.Designer.cs under the YourResourceFileName.resx node.

Do the same to the German resource file, change:

```
<Compile Include="YourResourceFileName.de.Designer.cs">
  <DependentUpon>YourResourceFileName.de.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="YourResourceFileName.de.resx">
```

to:

```
<Compile Include="YourResourceFileName.de.resx">
  <DependentUpon>YourResourceFileName.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

You will end up having something like this:
[image: YourResourceFile with several cultures]